# Point of Write-Error in Catch block

Tags: powershell

If you are only catching Exceptions to display the error in a more user friendly way, would there be any point in using Write-Error over Write-Host?
Write-Error would just show the Exception the same way it would if you didn't catch it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason you'd want to use `Write-Error` over `Write-Host` is that it will be written to the Powershell Error stream, and can be redirected if you wanted to do that later (e.g. running the script as a scheduled task, and want to capture that output to a log file).